# Multiple Availability Groups on one instance

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

I want to add second availability groups to Always on group and I need to change the port to 5023 but it is read-only as shown below:

[image]

The first availability group has an endpoint which is listening on port 5022. how can I change the port for second and third availability group?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The first availability group has an endpoint which is listening on port 5022. how can I change the port for second and third availability group?

All availability group traffic flows over a single endpoint and there is only one endpoint allowed per instance. So, in this case, since you already have an endpoint setup you only need create the new availability group.

Comment: I created a new availability group but for some reason, the default port is 5023 and I can't edit the value (it is read-only), any thoughts?

Comment: If you want to change the port you'll need to drop the endpoint and create it with the port you'd like as the port is part of the endpoint definition. You'll then need to update the endpoint url of the replica or it won't connect. Since the endpoint definitions don't change unless you drop and re-create it, I'm unsure how you first created one with port 5022 and then again with 5023. @Saber